# Navigational Properties remaining null, even after filtering them out

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm hitting a brick wall here, things are happening and they seem counter-intuitive.

I have a collection of entities, around 40k, which I am trying to convert to view models.
I am using the following code to do this.

```
var ents= (from ent in entities.ents
           where ent != null && ent.Prop1 != null && ent.Prop2 != null
           select ent).ToList();

ConcurrentBag<VmEnt> filtered = new ConcurrentBag<VmEnt>();
Parallel.ForEach(ents.AsParallel(), ent =>
{
     var vm = new VmEnt
                  {
                     Name = ent.Name,
                     Prop1 = new VmProp1
                                {
                                     Id = ent.Prop1.Id,
                                     Name = ent.Prop1.Name,
                                },
                     Prop2= new VmProp2
                                {
                                     Id = ent.Prop2.Id,
                                     Images = ent.Prop2.Images.Select(y => y.ImageUrl).ToList()
                                },
                     Prop3= ent.Prop3.Select(y => new VmProp3 
                                                     { 
                                                          Id = y.Id, 
                                                          Name = y.Name 
                                                     },
                   };
                   filtered.Add(vm);
 });
```

The issue I'm having is that in the parallel loop there are null references for ent.Prop1, even after these should have been filtered out. Am I missing something really simple? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `Prop3` that is null?  What is the exception?

Comment: The exception is a null reference on Prop1, which is unusual as Prop1Key, the FK field in Ent, is non-null.

Answer (score 0):

Is entities an EntityFramework context?
Are Prop1, Prop2 and Prop3 navigational properties?

If this is the case you need to load them also.
You can do this by using the Include method of the DbSet in the linq query (eager loading), using the Load method to load them later or you can enable lazy loading so that these navigational properties are loaded when you access the property. I personally prefer the first two methods depending on the use case.

Also you can simplify this code by creating the view model on the select of the linq query. This way you wont need to create a list just for iteranting it... you can even use AsParallel to create the view model objects.